# Mi app web de apps script no funciona con una cuenta diferente a la mia

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

He desarrollado una pequeña webapp usando app script, esta realiza todas las operaciones que debe hacer siempre y cuando mi cuenta este logueada en el dispositivo que la este usando, pero al momento de que la usa otro usuario con cuenta diferente esta no funciona, al momento de lanzarla lo he hecho con esta configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La me muestra correctamente el formulario html que debe mostrar, pero al momento de ejecutar una función que esta en Codigo.gs y que se activa en la instancia del ciclo de vida windows.onload me sale este error:

```
Uncaught  at loadEmployees
 at myOnLoadG
```

Siendo loadEmployees la funcion que llevama el onload y myOnloadG la funcion ubicada en Codigo.gs.

```
function myOnLoad(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessUsersSend).myOnLoadG();
}


function myOnLoadG() {
  var employees = loadEmployees() //funcion que carga registros de google sheet
  return employees
}
```

Porque no puedo alcanzar la función con una cuenta diferente a la mia?

Comment: estaria bien que mostrases el codigo con el que haces el login en la cuenta de google. para operar con una cuenta de google necesitas consentimiento explicito del usuario en el momento de utilizarla. pueden ocurrir muchas cosas, pero necesitamos ver, al menos esa parte del codigo.

Comment: No hago login como tal, al momento de ejecutar la app esta solicitar los permisos, lo que se hace es que en el onload se ejecuta una funcion que trae unos registros de una hoja de calculo de google para rellenar un select, edito la pregunta con el codigo de esa funcion.

Comment: asi sin tener mas informacion, sigo pensando que tiene que ver con la autentificacion de la cuenta de google, como bien pone en la propia configuracion: "los usuarios tendran que autorizar la ejecucion de la aplicacion web con los datos de su cuenta". he sufrido eso en mis carnes. si no haces login, como asocias la cuenta del usuario a la ejecucion de tu app?

Comment: ¿Podría ser cuestión de permisos de la hoja de cálculo? ¿Dónde está ubicada esa hoja de cálculo? ¿Usas una URL para acceder, cuál es? ¿Quiénes tienen acceso para leer o modificar?

Comment: Efectivamente Triby, la hoja de cálculo sobre la que se trabajaba estaba restringida a unas cuantas cuentas, al volverla pública se ha solucionado, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Google app script ejecuta la función según implementación para el caso de las Web Apps. En tu caso si quieres que otro usuario ejecute la misma implementación publicada, puedes:

**Opción 1:** Añadir a esa persona como un colaborador del script y así podrá ejecutarlo la web app una vez que la implemente.

**Opción 2:** Publicar la web app, y que el resto de las personas la ejecute como vos mismo (Yo tu correo de Gmail) y ponerle cualquier usuario (esto seria incluso anónimos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre recuerda antes de publicar, seleccionar la funcion `doGet(e)` y darle a `run` antes de publicar la nueva implementación.